# A tool to automatically generate PHPUnit tests?

Tags: php, phpunit

I was wondering - is there a tool which will look at my PHP code and automatically generate a PHPUnit test for it? Or is there a tool like this for any other language, which I might be able to port to PHP?

I'm not talking about generating a skeleton. I was thinking that it would be possible for a tool to look at tokenized PHP and determine the code paths through a method, and then automatically generate a test for each code path, creating mocks and setting "expects" calls as necessary.

Even if there's no tool that currently does it, might such a task be feasible or am I overlooking something?

Comment: Testing your code behaves as it does isn't nearly as useful as testing it behaves as it should.

Comment: I agree with AndreKR. Assuming I have a piece of code working correctly before I start writing the tests for it, "behaves as it does" is a subset of "behaves as it should". Any change that alters the way my code works should cause a unit test failure and make me take a second look at the code - even if it apparently continues to work properly.

Comment: Sharing on Github might lead to developing great tool. In time of course. I'm info it

Comment: @BrianKendig behaves as it does is not a subset of behaves as it should. If it does something it shouldnt do, then its not in the set..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Turns out there is no tool that does this currently, so I wrote one (with help from my colleagues). Not complete - just enough to explore the concept. By using nikic's PHP-Parser(https://github.com/nikic/PHP-Parser), it's possible to find all the method calls in the methods of a class, and then mocks can be created for them.

At the very least, I might eventually get it to the point where I can use it to make some fill-in-the-blank unit tests.

Comment: hey, do you plan on sharing this tool? I'd be very curious to see it

Comment: No plans to share it; it wasn't useful. Turns out that if code is complex enough that an automated tool is helpful, then the code is too complex and should be refactored so that writing unit tests is trivially simple.

Comment: good point, but I was thinking of it from the perspective of non complex code, but lots of it...

Comment: @BrianKendig, I have a slightly different take on this, and am planning to build something in this direction. I totally agree that any code complex enough to benefit significantly from this needs to be refactored, but *THAT* is exactly where such a tool is helpful. The point of refactoring is to change the program design/structure *WITHOUT* changing the resulting behavior. A tool long kenyou describe could be invaluable in ensuring that the refactored code does indeed not change any behavior. If you could contribute what you've come up with so far, it may be a helpful starting point. thanks.

Comment: I just noticed a major typo above. "tool long kenyou describe" should have been: "tool like you describe"... sorry.

Comment: Automatically generating unit tests might be helpful for developers who already have confidence from manually writing integration tests, but corporate policies dictate that they must write unit tests. In this case having a tool to do the mocking and test generation for you would be helpful to satisfy the requirement of 100% unit code coverage.

Answer (score 3):

Unlikely to be feasible.

Current techniques for automatic test generation depend on the presence of specifications for the code's behavior, not just an implementation. Inferring a spec from PHP code is not necessarily easy for a *human*, let alone a machine, so I seriously doubt that it'd be possible to make this work for any real-world code.

Comment: I'm not as interested in a unit test that only says "if I pass X as an argument, then it returns Y". Given code that works properly, I can write a unit test for it even if I don't know what it does - all I have to do is choose a code path, make assertions about the external method calls along that code path, and make assertions about the return value from that code path. It's this kind of test that I think a tool would be able to write for me quite nicely.

Comment: 11 years later and we have just such tools that do this and so much more. Pretty feasible today.